# How to select distinct values and their usage in table?

Tags: sql

I have only 1 column. I need statistics about it's values and their usage:

```
Value | Count
-----------------
NULL  |   41 (91%)
''    |   3  (3%)
'FOO' |   2  (2%)
'BAR' |   1  (1%)
```

Also I need to perform such query for every column in database. Is there utility to help me with such reports? I asking about Postgresql/Mysql.

Comment: Following code show only first column (in random order) of table I need:


    SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName FROM TableName;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select value , count(*) from table 
group by value
```

Replace `table` for your table name and `value` for your column name

With Percentages:

```
select value 
 ,count(*)
 ,COUNT(*)/(select cast(COUNT(*) as decimal) as Total from table) as Usage 
 from table 
group by value
```

Comment: Damn, was so easy! I had feeling about DISTINCT and virtual tables / joins is overkill for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Common table expressions to the rescue (tested on PostgreSQL 9):

```
WITH a AS (SELECT COUNT(*) AS max FROM t)
SELECT v, COUNT(v), (COUNT(v)::FLOAT / a.max) * 100
  FROM t, a
 GROUP BY v, a.max
 ORDER BY COUNT(v) DESC;
```

Comment: What's nice about the CTE (WITH …) is that that count will only be run the one time.